# Jquery Autocomplete from json list all elements

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In my script to autocomplete I set a json file:

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "test.json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { term: request.term },
        success: function(data) {
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return { label: item.name_test };
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

**The JSON file**

```
[{
  "id_test": "7",
  "name_test": "Tejido",
  "price": "65"
}, {
  "id_test": "8",
  "name_test": "Semen",
  "price": "120"
}, {
  "id_test": "6",
  "name_test": "Saliva",
  "price": "20"
}, {
  "id_test": "2",
  "name_test": "Analisis urinario",
  "price": "150"
}, {
  "id_test": "3",
  "name_test": "Analisis sanguineo",
  "price": "1502"
}, {
  "id_test": "4",
  "name_test": "Analisis fecal",
  "price": "20"
}]
```

But when I type a name into the input, all the elements are listed.

What is my error?

Comment: Are you filtering your results on the server? Because you should be.

Comment: is not filtering, I know that is the objective of autocomplete, list the elements with the same words or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a remote source, as your code is using, you must need to filter the results in the server side or in the `success` callback from the ajax call. In your case you can use something like:

```
...
success: function (data) {
    var tag_val = $("#tags").val();
    response($.map(data, function (item) {

        //filtering results....
        if (item.name_test.indexOf(tag_val) != -1) {
            return {
                label: item.name_test
            };
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: @Samueledrei you're welcome. Just pointing out that this is not the best approach, because you're always getting the whole json to filter some results. The best would be filtering on the server side or not using a remote source